# Odoo delegation inheritance delete corresponding records of inherited class

Tags: python, inheritance, odoo, odoo-9

I've extended a default class using _inherits.  I am using Odoo v9.

```
class new_product_uom(models.Model):  
_inherits = {'product.uom':'uomid', }  
_name = "newproduct.uom" 
uomid = fields.Many2one('product.uom',ondelete='cascade', required=True).
#declare variables and functions specific to new_product_uom
sellable = fields.Boolean('Sell products using this UoM?', default=True)
[...]
```

If I delete the corresponding record in product.uom, the new_product_uom is deleted.

If I were to delete a new_product_uom record, nothing happens to the corresponding product_uom record.

I'd like for BOTH records to be automatically deleted when either is deleted.  Is there a way I can do this? Thanks in advance for the help.

Clarification:

product.uom is a default odoo class. It holds UoM records (inches, centimeters, etc).  I use delegation inheritance to extend this class. See:
https://www.odoo.com/documentation/9.0/howtos/backend.html#model-inheritance

So, when I add a record for newproduct.uom, a record is automatically created under the model product.uom.  I can assign the values of the corresponding record in product.uom by addressing them in newproduct.uom.

For my uses, it will be intended as a Parent->child relation, with newproduct.uom being the parent, and the default product.uom being the child.  I chose this method of inheritance to allow quicker creation and modification of related values, as well as a separation of functions (rather than overriding the default methods for default operations).

Comment: Im not sure if I clearly understand the relationship between the models. I apologise for that. Could you edit your question to make the relationships between the models clearer?

Comment: Hi Phillip.  I added a bit more to the question... but the gist of it that my new class is really sort of a Parent->child relation.  Its one to one.  If I create a new_product_uom instance, it creates a product.uom instance. Right now, if I delete the child (product.uom), it deletes the parent.  I really need it to work in the other direction, where if I delete the Parent, the child is removed too.  

This would be easy if I wasn't using delegation inheritance, but I decided this would be best for my model... so I'd like to keep that.

Comment: So you are saying that both the parent and child have a Many2one and both have cascade on delete?

Comment: That is what I would normally do, but I haven't declared anything in product.uom .  Even if I manually declared a Many2one relation in product.uom (pointing to newproduct.uom), I can't cascade ondelete because I can't set required=true.  It won't delete it unless I set required=true, and the default unit of measure class should not always have a newproduct.uom assigned to it.  The default product.uom really shouldn't know about my new class at all.

I saw some posts using unlink(), but I have no idea how its used.  There is next to no documentation on it.

Comment: Yes. Your other option is to override unlink()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your parent class override unlink. Not sure if I have the correct class name. Delete the child record and then delete the current record.

```
@api.multi
def unlink(self):
    self.uom_id.unlink()
    return super(new_product_uom, self).unlink()
```